# Python: dictionary for each item matching problem

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement, break

I am trying to look for **a correspond value to the key** in dictionary on Hackerank.

I tried to print out every process to debug, and I found the process ran quite as I expected, however, the result was really weird. my output shows that the statement did read the right name "harry", but it cannot find "harry" in my dictionary. Can someone pls give me some ideas on this, thank you!

Here are my codes:

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    n = int(input()) #input how many pairs of name-phone in this phonebook
    d = dict()

    for count in range(n):
        name, phone = input().split()
        d[name] = phone
    print(d)

    while True:
        search_phone = input() #input the name
        print('enter new name') #debug

        for name, phone in d.items():
            if search_phone == name :
                print(name + '=' + phone)
                print(search_phone + ' bingle, continue to enter another name')
                break

            elif search_phone != name:
                print('Not found')
                print(search_phone + ' no match, continue to enter another name')
                break
```

sample input is:

```
3
sam 99912222
tom 11122222
harry 12299933
sam
edward
harry
```

expected output:

```
sam=99912222
Not found
harry=1229993
```

my output is:

```
{'sam': '99912222', 'tom': '11122222', 'harry': '12299933'}    
enter new name
sam=99912222
sam bingle, continue to enter another name
enter new name
Not found
edward no match, continue to enter another name
enter new name
Not found
harry no match, continue to enter another name 
###my question is why it did read harry but goes to no match?
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [MVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  We should not have to manually enter data: you hard-code it and produce the error.  Your program contains dict input, search input, and other processing; which of these contains the problem?  It's your task to narrow this down before posting.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. The only explanation you provided is _"I am trying to look for a correspond value to the key in dictionary"_ and it doesn't seem to be a working English sentence. May I suggest that you edit your question?

Comment: @Prune Hi sorry for that, I've added the expected output in my question, and my main question is in the last query of my code, when it inputs "harry", my output shows it successfully read "harry", but strangely, it didn't go to the "search_phone == name " condition, it goes to "!=" condition,

Comment: @NicolasGervais Hi, sorry it isn't clear enough, I've added the expected output and my problem is in the last query, when I input "harry", it shows that it did read "harry" as I expected, however, it didn't go to the condition " search_phone == name ", it goes to != condition. And it ended up saying "not found" in the last query.
so i wonder what is wrong with my  dict.items() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thats happen cuz u put `break` in ur else statement. So, the code will break at the first loop, and can't get the next items in `d`. So, u have to erase break in else statement.

But we have new problem, in every loop there will execute the else statement if `search_phone != name`. So, we have solve this. U can try this one(sorry for bad english)

```
 while True:
        search_phone = input() #input the name
        print('enter new name') #debug
        valid = False

        for name, phone in d.items():
            if search_phone == name :
                print(name + '=' + phone)
                print(search_phone + ' bingle, continue to enter another name')
                valid = True
                break

        if not valid:
            print('name:', name)
            print('Not found')
            print(search_phone + ' no match, continue to enter another name')
```